# C++ Copy Construcor does not call the Base Constructor

Tags: c++, copy, polymorphism

Why does the default copy constructor not call the base constructor of `monster` but when I include a user-defined copy-constructor in `troll` it calls the parent (i.e.: `monster`) constructor?

As I think it works as follow: Create the base object and after that copy the elements inside.

Here is a sample code:

```
using std::cout;

struct monster {
    monster() {
        cout << "a monster is bread\n";
    }
    ~monster() {
        cout << "monster killed\n";
    }
    void health() {
        cout << "immortal?\n";
    }
    virtual void attack() {
        cout << "roar\n";
    }
};

struct troll: monster {
    troll() {
        cout << "a troll grows\n";
    }
    ~troll() {
        cout << "troll petrified\n";
    }
protected:
    int myhealth { 10 };
};

struct forum_troll: troll {
    forum_troll() :
            troll { } {
        cout << "not quite a monster\n";
    }
    ~forum_troll() {
        cout << "troll banned\n";
    }
};

int main() {
    cout << "a ------\n";
    forum_troll ft { };
    cout << "copy \n \n";
    troll t { ft };
    cout << "end \n \n";
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Why does the default copy constructor not call the Base Constructor but when I include a user-defined copy-constructor it calls the parent constructor?

What gets called is the *copy constructor* (not the *default constructor*) for the `monster` base class. The reason is that before the `troll`'s *default-generated copy constructor* is called, the *copy constructor* of its base class (i.e.: `monster`) is called.

Paying attention to your code:

```
forum_troll ft { };
troll t { ft };
```

In the second statement, it is clear that `troll`'s default-generated copy constructor (because you didn't provide any user-defined copy constructor) will be called. It is `monster`'s copy constructor what is called (prior to `troll`'s copy constructor), not its default constructor, because this is what the default-copy constructor does, i.e.: calling the base's copy constructor.

This default behaviour makes sense, since `troll`'s base class is `monster` (a `troll` object is a `monster` object). Therefore, before copy constructing a `troll`, a `monster` has to be copy constructed.

When you provide a user-defined copy constructor for `troll` you are probably not explicitly calling `monster`'s copy constructor and therefore `monster` default constructor is what gets called.

Comment: yes, I didn't called the copy constructor of the Base class. As for clarification: The default copy constructor calls the base default copy constructor and so on?

Comment: The *default-generated copy constructor* calls the base's copy constructor (regardless of whether that base's copy constructor is *default-generated* or *user-defined*).

Comment: This means if I user define a copy constructor I should explicitly call the base's copy constructor and not the default constructor?

Comment: Well, such an statement may be too broad. *Copy constructing* an object implies **constructing** the object and therefore the object's *base classes*. I recommend you to think about the **semantics of copying**. For example, in your code, you display *"a monster is bread"* by means of the default constructor as a sign of a `monster` being bred. However, doesn't copy constructing breed a `monster` ? Well, according to your code, it doesn't. Maybe it should be *"a monster is cloned"* for the copy constructor. Whatever makes sense for your application.

Comment: BTW, I would strongly recommend you to read this as well: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/461203/when-to-use-virtual-destructors

Comment: There were also some methods and properties like health I stripped out.